# Tkinter: Opening a URL via Dropdown. Need to specify Item from List

Tags: python, tkinter

Another one of these puzzles where Im sure I got the right idea but I cant seem to implement it.

Im trying to make a dropdown that instantly opens the URL to whatever column 1 of the list says but I'm not sure if I maybe need a dictionary and call it from that, do I need to define the list by columns...

So I figured out how to open up URLS from a TreeView but now Im figuring out how to open the URL from a Dropdown. I want the {*spec*} to be populated by only the first item from the list (Pepperoni) in this case.

```
QUICKJUMP_1 = [ 
    ["--", "--"],
    ["Pepperoni", "Pizza"],
]
def openGoogle():
    _spec_ = QUICKJUMP_1
    url = f'https://google.com/{_spec_}'
    webbrowser.open(url)


quickjump = StringVar()
quickjump.set(QUICKJUMP_1[0])

spec = ttk.Combobox(root, width=30, textvariable=quickjump, state="") 
spec['values'] = [item[1] for item in QUICKJUMP_1]
spec.place(x=300, y=400)
spec.current(0)
spec.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", openGoogle)
```

EDIT:

I updated the code as it was figured out how to make it actually open up the URL but as it stands right now all it currently does is just opens up the first part of the list whatever part of the list the "*spec* = QUICKJUMP" points it to i.e [1] = item 2.

So I need someway to tell it to pick from the drop box and only the first part.

Comment: Add code that other people can simply copy from the question, run and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code given is not a working code, I will write down an example and you can hopefully figure it out from it:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser

root = Tk()
base_url = 'www.google.com/{}'

options = ['--','Peperoni Pizza']

def open_url(e): # e.widget is the widget that triggers the event, here, combobox
    if e.widget.get() != options[0]: # If the value is not '--'
       value = e.widget.get()
       just_the_flavour = value.split(' ')[0] # This will split the text 'Peperoni Pizza' into two items in a list
       # It does this where there is ' ', ie, a blank space, so the list will be ['Peperoni','Pizza']
       # Then we take just the first item from it use [0]
      
       url = base_url.format(just_the_flavour)
       webbrowser.open(url)
    
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root,values=options)
combobox.pack()
combobox.current(0) # Set the first value to the first in the list

combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',open_url) # Bind to the function

root.mainloop()
```

I have explained it on the comments to understand it on the go.